# Editing apex code after deploying to production (using change sets)

Tags: apex, change-set

I understand that any edits to apex classes have to be done in the Sandbox. If I'm deploying changes via a Change Set, does anyone know if I have to first DELETE the apex class in production? Will the change set overwrite it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to worry, your change set will overwrite what's in production.